# Adding clickable help icons to navbar menu items in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add clickable and hoverable little help icons, which floats to the right side of the corresponding navbar menu item. My problem is that bootstrap applies its styles in a way that it doesn't seem to be a quick easy task.

My icon would be something like this (using FontAwesome):

```
<span class="navmenu-help-icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></span>
```

My current LESS code for the icon is (based on the styling of the `a` element):

```
.navbar-nav > li > .navmenu-help-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background-color: lighten(@navbar-inverse-bg, 20%);
}
```

I can't wrap the link and my button in a `div` because bootstrap exepcts the `a` element as a first level child of its `li`. If I place my icon after the `a`, I couldn't figure out how to align them horizontally, it always goes under the link. I guess because the `a` element's `display: block` style.

I'm targetting only modern browsers (full CSS3 support expected).

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but why not simply put the icon inside the `a` tag, like `<li><a href="#">Help <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a></li>`?

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Help <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**Update based on comments (same row icon and text on mobile layout)**

To show an icon with another link next to one of the navigation items both in *desktop* and *mobile* views, I've added the class `nav-iconitem` to the these `li`'s. This changes the `a` tags from `display: block` to `display: inline-block`. The `li` should contain a separate `a.nav-iconitem__text` tag for the text and a `a.nav-iconitem__icon` for the icon. The classes `nav-iconitem__text` and `.nav-iconitem__icon` are used to change the distance between the text and the icon.

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.nav > li.nav-iconitem > a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav > li.nav-iconitem > a.nav-iconitem__text {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.nav > li.nav-iconitem > a.nav-iconitem__icon {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-iconitem"><a href="#" class="nav-iconitem__text">Help</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-iconitem__icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Regular</a>        
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**Update based on comments (float icon to the right)**

To make the icon float to the right, the easiest way might be to set `position: relative` to the `.nav-iconitem` and `position: absolute`, `top: 0` and `right: 0` to the `.nav-iconitem__icon`. As the icon might overlap the `.nav-iconitem__text` you unfortunately need to add a fixed sized `padding-right` to the `.nav-iconitem`.

It might be possible to achieve this with a `display: table`, but as tables have the tendency to grow you might need a fixed width somewhere anyway. I would prefer having a fixed width on an icon instead of a container containing text.

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.nav > li.nav-iconitem {
  display: relative;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.nav > li.nav-iconitem > a.nav-iconitem__text {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.nav > li.nav-iconitem > a.nav-iconitem__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;  
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-iconitem"><a href="#" class="nav-iconitem__text">Help</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-iconitem__icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Regular</a>        
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: I didn't want this originally because of the problems of "clicks". This should work on mobile devices as well, and I wanted to be sure that the icon is nicely clickable and not easy to misclick and navigate to the link instead. But will examine it, probably a good amount of padding would solve this problem.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. That also makes it impossible to use a different `li` for the help icon as on mobile that would be shown in a new row instead of to the right of the "Help" menu item. Having nested clickable areas doesn't sound like a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update, another problem is that the help icon should be "floated" (I mean visually) to the right (or left), and the link should be still fill the entire row. In your example the link got small. I'm about to find a right solution, placing the icon to the left, and using display:table-cell to both the link and the icon span, and setting width:99% to the link to span through the LI. If you update your answer that way I will accept it because it was motivating :)

Comment: Ah.. my solution is not correct either, it's fine when in submenu or collapsed state, but breaks when it's used on top level menu when in horizontal state. Still experimenting further...

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was to use the `table-cell` display mode inside the LI-s where an icon should be displayed. I've allowed myself to place the icon on the left to make things a bit easier.

Here is the LESS source which handles submenus and collapsed mode as well. Note that I use Jasny Bootstrap's Offcanvas navbar, so some part refers to that.

```
.navbar {
    li.with-icon {
        & > a {
            display: table-cell;
            padding-left: 0;            
        }

        & > .navmenu-help-icon {
            display: table-cell;
            padding: @nav-link-padding;
            padding-right: 8px;
            line-height: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1em;
            //background-color: lighten(@navbar-inverse-bg, 20%);
        }
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
        li.with-icon {
            & > .navmenu-help-icon {
                display: table-cell;
                padding: 3px 10px;
            }

            & > a {
                width: 99%; // force spanning till right border
                padding-left: 0;
            }
        }
    }

    .offcanvas.canvas-slid {
        li.with-icon {
            & > .navmenu-help-icon {
                display: table-cell;
                padding: @nav-link-padding;                
            }

            & > a {
                width: 99%; // force spanning till right border
                padding-left: 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the HTML markup looks like this:

```
<li class="with-icon">
   <span class="help-icon navmenu-help-icon" title="Some description"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></span>
   <a href="#">The link</a>          
</li>
```